# What does "влип" mean?

Tags: перевод

In this song lyric:

> Мой парень снова влип в дурные дела

The word "влип" appears (I checked two lyrics sites), but I can't find it in any online dictionaries. What does it mean? And would the sentence still be grammatically correct without it? (ie. "Мой парень снова в дурные дела")

Comment: No, the sentence without this word is ungrammatical.

Comment: "Мой парень - снова в дурные дела" this will be grammatical :>

Comment: https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ozhegov-term-3456.htm - словарь Ожегова
I don't know which dictionaries you are watching. Literally it mean get into a viscous, thick, - sticky (в-лип-нуть, лип-кий, like a leaf of tree липа (linden)) -  liquid or substance like the syrup, glue or swamp

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Влип* is the past tense of the verb *влипнуть*, which literally means *to get into something sticky*. Here, this word is used with a colloquial meaning very close to English **to get (oneself) into a mess**.

Comment: So *влипнуть* is an irregular verb?

Comment: @JackM In what sense irregular?

Comment: @JackM Maybe you mean "perfective" verb? Russian verbs have a few types of conjugation, and thus cannot be simply divided into regular/irregular as in English.

Comment: Well, past tense verbs normally end in л, but this one doesn't.

Comment: @JackM This is not considered to be "some irregularity" but rather "yet another pattern". Quite a few verbs ending in consonant+'нуть' are like this: no suffix `-л` in masc. sing. past tense.

Answer (score 6):

This widely used informal expression means to get (oneself) into an unpleasant situation with inevitable consequences. There's also a famous saying, "Bлип, очкарик!" (You're stuck, foureyes!), from a very popular Soviet movie where those words are said to the main character who wears glasses and literally gets stuck in a tar pit.

Answer (score 2):

It usually means "got stuck in something", as in **Ты влип в неприятности** *You've got problems*, which merely states a fact, i.e. it doesn't sound threatening or wish hardship on the listener.

**However** bear in mind that it's a standalone phrase not usually followed by anything:
**Ты влип**. *You've got problems*.

Hope this helps. =)